# Does it matter if my site uses the same keyword in different parts of the URL on different pages?

Tags: url, seo

I have a site which uses the word "page" in different points in the url depending on the webpage you're on. So one would be "example.com/catalog/page" where you look at a bunch of products, but then on "example.com/page/contact_us" there is a static webpage with contact information.
Is it worth the hit in organic traffic to make this change or does it even matter to search engines if that keyword is used like this?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I guess SEs and users will both have a bad time on your URLs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same situation with one of my websites when I had no other choice than structuring the URLs like so. Never had a problem, and my rankings are more than good.

However you should be aware that keyword stuffing in URLs may cause to you SEO penalties. Avoid having too many pages on your site that have a URL with the same keyword.